# AWS API Gateway HTTP Type Request Body Mapping Security

Tags: amazon-web-services

Many times 3rd party REST endpoints ask that your API key be appended to the query string if you are calling the endpoint in javascript, but this means that anyone can see your API key.

In order to get around this I set up a "proxy" API in AWS API Gateway using the HTTP type and point it at my 3rd party endpoint.  In order to pass my API key to the 3rd party endpoint I create a body mapping template in the integration request step and hard code it there. I then call my AWS API in my javascript which calls the 3rd party and passes along my API key.

Is this considered safe or is there a way someone could ultimately get my API key?

Comment: Q1: What would prevent anybody from calling your "Proxy" API on your behalf, even if they don't know your API key?

Q2: Why would the 3rd party request that you use Javascript to make the API call?

Comment: As @KhalidT. said it doesn't sound very secure.  I'd think that the API gateway should instead pull the key from, for example, a HTTP header and put it into the url.  That way only people with the key in the first place can call the remote API.